# What is the Best theoretical Distribution for Bimodal Distribution?

Tags: python, statistics, ecdf

I have a dataset displaying a bimodal distribution, confirmed through a dip statistic test with a significantly small P-value, providing evidence against the null hypothesis of unimodality. I’ve calculated the empirical cumulative distribution function using Python with Numpy, and visualized the results using Matplotlib and Seaborn. Could someone guide me on determining the best theoretical distribution for this bimodal dataset? I’m seeking insights on real-world practices and relevant concepts. Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think your question is off-topic.  Essentially this is a mathematical / statistical question, not a programming question.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, I’ll post this question there!